# Node.js project make installer

Tags: javascript, websocket, windows-installer

Here's my problem.

I'm working in a project that has a server/cliente websocket. And I need to make some easy instalation file for client project. I've searched and found some options. One of this is Electron framework.

So here is my question. Is Electron the best option to do this? Another point, the client has only line interface.

This project was made to work in windows and linux computers.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much more about your project, have you thought about a PWA? They are fairly easy to get started and look like a native app once installed.

Comment: make long history short the project is: Server send a string to client. This istring is a SQL Query, Client execute and send the result back to the Server.

What tools do you recomend to make a PWA in Node.js? I'm new in Node programming, I do only know the basics about javascript

Comment: There's a bunch of tutorials online to make a PWA that you can just copy the code from. You could also just have the client use Postman to make the request to the server to get the string. Again, I'm still not really understanding the whole scope of your project so just throwing things at your wall to see if it sticks.